# MovieClip changes Stage alignment

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am loading a `MovieClip` using `MovieClipLoader`. When the `MovieClip` starts playing, it changes the alignment of my stage to LT, which incorrectly repositions all the other objects on my stage.

Is there anyway for me to:

1. Prevent the `MovieClip` from changing the alignment of my stage?
2. Adding an event handler to an appropriate event, so that I can reset the stage alignment when it gets changed?

I have already tried resetting the stage alignment on the `onLoadInit` event of `MovieClipLoader` and the `onEnterFrame` event of `MovieClip`, but both seem to reset the alignment too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `_lockroot = true` on the offending clip once you've loaded it, this may keep it from messing with your stage.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001321.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set `_lockroot = true` in the `onLoadComplete` event handler of my `MovieClipLoader`, but this did not solve the problem. My event handler is as follows:

```
lLoadListener.onLoadComplete = function(target_mc:MovieClip)
{
    Debug.info("lockroot is " + target_mc._lockroot);
    target_mc._lockroot = true;
    Debug.info("lockroot is " + target_mc._lockroot);
}
```

But this just prints `lockroot is undefined` twice. I have also tried to add `_lockroot = true` to the `onLoad` event handler of the `MovieClip` I am loading, but after some investigation and debug trace, it seems that the `onLoad` event is never being called.

Is there any reason why `target_mc._lockroot` should be returning `undefined`? Is it related at all to `onLoad` ever being called?